# are they adding copy_if to c++0x?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

It's very annoying that `copy_if` is not in C++. Does anyone know if it will be in C++0x?

Comment: FWIW, it was left out of the present standard by mistake :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the C++0x is not yet finalized, you can only take a look at the most recent [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2857.pdf).

Comment: By now, C++0x is pretty well finalized, and the most recent draft is darn close to what the final version will be.

Comment: I agree, I was just reading that gcc 4.4 already has some support for the draft.

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime, it's not very hard to make your own `copy_if()` using `remove_copy_if()`:

```
#include <functional>

struct my_predicate : std::unary_function<my_arg_type, bool> {
    bool operator()(my_arg_type const& x) const { ... }
};

// To perform "copy_if(x, y, z, my_predicate())", write:
remove_copy_if(x, y, z, std::not1(my_predicate()));
```

Using `not1()` requires your predicate class to supply a nested type, `argument_type`, identifying the type of the argument -- as shown above, one convenient way to do this is to derive from `unary_function<T, U>`, where `T` is the argument type.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, in case someone googles his/her way to this question, it should be mentioned that now (in C++11 and later) **there is** a [**copy if**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) algorithm. It behaves as expected (copies the elements in a range, for which some predicate returns true, to another range).

A typical use case would be

```
std::vector<int> foo{ 25, 15, 5, -5, -15 };
std::vector<int> bar;

// copy only positive numbers:
auto it = std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(bar), 
            [](int i){return !(i<0);
          });
```