# @result_list = grep { test($_) } @unfiltered_list in other languages?

Tags: perl, language-features, filtering, porting, metalanguage

One of the features I love in Perl is the LISP-inspired (?) ability to filter content out of a list of things with the simple syntax

```
@result_list = grep { test($_) } @unfiltered_list;
```

where test function will be applied to all the items of @unfiltered_list to produce the @result_list.

Is that a feature that exists in other languages as well ? (PHP? Python?) Otherwise, how could I easily hint non-Perlers (students) about what I mean through such code ?

SOLUTION: `filter` in most languages, [as seen on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29#Implementation). Thanks for the tip, dudes.

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind? As you pointed out, this is available in Lisp and its variants.

Comment: in most high level languages, if they support `grep` it is called `filter`.  `grep` is two characters shorter and thus more perlish (and more unixish) :)

Comment: Eric Strom: "most" implies you know of several; can you mention what they are?

Comment: @ysth: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)#Implementation .  The name `select` is also reasonably common.

Comment: @ether: The goal was to explain something to computer science students that have some earlier experience with Java, possibly have been exposed to PHP/Python although I can't be sure. I'd avoid the "select" reference, as my intent was to provide an interpretation of the ADA "select" construct :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python there is the [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
result_list = filter(test,unfiltered_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++0x you can do this using [`std::copy_if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794320/are-they-adding-copy-if-to-c0x) with a `back_inserter` iterator. Lambda functions make this even easier too.

Comment: Or in C++03, if you don't mind writing the simple function template `copy_if` yourself.

Comment: It's even easier than writing std::copy_if yourself -- std::remove_copy_if can be used with std::not (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448817/why-there-is-no-stdcopy-if-algorithm)

Comment: thanks for pointing out. Though as usual, simple solutions in C++ turns frightening.